# Skip over an HttpMessageConverter if canRead and canWrite are false

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, http-message-converter, spring-boot-2

I have a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that I add to the top of the converters list:

```
 @Override
 public void extendMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(0, customJacksonMessageConverter());
}
```

However, there are times when I need to skip over this and use the Spring default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, like when I want to update the logging level of my application through Spring Boot Admin.  In my custom converter, I have overridden both `canRead()` and `canWrite()` with an added debug log line to see what the value returned is, and I can see they both return `false` when I need to skip over.  However, parsing using the default fails.  If I remove my custom converter from the list, then the default does work.

My list of converters looks like this:

```
com.meanwhile.in.hell.converters.json.CustomJacksonMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter
```

I don't see why if my custom converter returns `false` for `canRead()` and `canWrite()`, that it doesn't just skip over this and continue down the list of converters until it gets to the default Spring JSON converter.